# Impact of Google Founding Choices on CLS

Tags: pagespeed

I'm trying to performance my site, but I'm still bothered with one problem.
For example, my site and these similar: https://www.imeteo.sk/clanok/streda-prinesie-teple-a-dusne-pocasie-miestami-sa-objavia-aj-intenzivnejsie-burky  have PageSpped Insights Cumulative Lyout Shift 0.31.

If I look at the issues, the only issue is with the Google Funding Choices logo. CLS problem with PageSpeed Insights:

[image: CLS problem with PageSpeed Insights]

How to eliminate this problem so that it does not affect the overall CLS?

Comment: Have you found a solution this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the layout shift may be caused by the fact that the browser doesn't know the size of your logo image until it is loaded. So when the popup shows up, the size of image element is 0,0. Later it changes to the size of your image (after loading) - which causes the layout shift.

I would try to define the image's width and height. Add a class to your css:

```
.fc-header-image {
    width:200px;  //put your logo dimensions here
    height:100px;
}
```

If it doesn't help, I would consider removing the logo image whatsoever. In my case, the CLS of Google Funding Choices - popup without logo - is around 0.03, which is condidered a 'good' value by core web vitals.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and sometimes it displays CLS issue on the same page and sometimes not and I don't have any images on content popup.